# Docker-Compose Network Issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: django, linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I've been developing my python application using `Django` with `PostgreSQL` and `Nginx` and `Docker`, driven by `Docker-Compose` on my `Macbook M1`. And recently, decided to deploy it on the remote server, which has `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`, but encountered really weird issue.

My web application says, that it cannot resolve host `postgresql` (service at docker-compose file, which you can find down below), however, it works fine on my machine, can it be related to the Docker?

It might be because I installed imcompatible versions of `Docker` and `Docker-compose` on this remote server or apparently used wrong commands, but not really sure about that, as I haven't gained enough experience of working with `Ubuntu` yet.

My Macbook's M1 Docker & Docker-compose Versions:

~ `Docker` - 20.10.12

~ `Docker-Compose` - 1.29.2

My Remote's Server Ubuntu Docker & Docker-compose Versions:

~ `Docker` - 20.10.23

~ `Docker-compose` - 1.29.2

My docker-compose.yaml file

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:

  nginx_server:
    container_name: "nginx_web_server"
    image: crazycoderrr/vdnh_nginx_server:latest # образ nginx для нашего проекта
    ports:
      - "8010:80"
    depends_on:
      - application_service 
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - private_network

  application_service:
    container_name: "application_server"
    image: crazycoderrr/vdnh_application:latest # образ backend сервиса нашего приложения
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    env_file: ./env/application.env
    networks:
      - private_network 

  postgresql:
    container_name: "postgresql_database"
    image: crazycoderrr/vdnh_postgres_db:latest # образ для postgres нашего проекта
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres_password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "vdnh_db"
    ports:
      - "5436:5436"
    command:
      - -p 5436 
    networks:
      - private_network

networks:
  private_network:
    external: True
    name: private-project-network # приватная сеть, соединяющая все компоненты проекта
      # должна быть создана вручную!!!! <docker network create private-project-network -d bridge>
```

`application.env` file, that is used in my project

```
DATABASE_NAME="vdnh_db"
DATABASE_HOST="postgresql"
DATABASE_PORT=5436
DATABASE_USER="postgres_user"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="postgres_password"
```

If you are familiar with Django, this log message might be useful

```py
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
application_server     |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
application_server     |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
nginx_web_server       | exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
postgresql_database    | exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
application_server     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
application_server     |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgresql" to address: Name or service not known
```

What I did on the remote server:

1. Installed Docker using this command from the official website:

```bash
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

2. Then, I installed Docker-Compose using the following command from the official website:

```bash
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

3. Created private network for my project

```bash
$ docker network create private-project-network -d bridge
```

4. Then cloned gitlab repository with the project and run `docker-compose up -d` command
5. Then I decided to check logs using `docker-compose logs` and figured out, that it broken

If you have any thoughts on that, please, write out down in the comment section :)

Comment: I'm not really all that familiar with docker, does [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/913066/how-to-allow-docker-containers-to-see-each-other-by-their-name) help?

Comment: Any luck with this issue @crazycoder?